# Code Review for Automated Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, code-reviews

Writing **automated unit tests** is followed as a part of our development process.

We also do have an established code review process for the development code that is written.

Should the test code be reviewed? If yes how to make it less time-consuming for both the author and the reviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Test code is still code and shoould have same level of quality as production code.

You shouldn't bother about it consuming time, as that is often not the bottleneck to creating high-quality software.

Comment: I agree that Test Code may be worthy of review.  I have a minor quibble, and disagree that it should have the "same level of quality".  For example, Strings for error messages and test names need not be extracted into separate constants, a config file, be capable of internationalization, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Code reviews are used for more than just ensuring your program doesnt break.

Its also used to ensure that best practices are followed, design patterns are used in the right areas and that the code follows 'clean code principles' (variable naming conventions, proper documentation). It can also be used so other developers who may maintain your project have a better grasp of what's going on.

Also unit tests dont always catch all runtime errors (even though it should). Sometimes a developer may see something a unit test didnt catch saving you tons of time down the line

Comment: Yeahhh, but... Doesn't really answer the question that was asked, does it?

Comment: ah yeah ur right, now that I re-read it Im not answering 'should we review the test code or the latter question'